# (Python) Can't Print all the Contents of the Text File

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, text-files, spyder

I have tried my best to print ALL the contents of my text file. But I still can't comprehend what is wrong. Here is my code:

```
Input = input("TYPE: ")

with open("tryme.txt","a+") as f:
    f.write(Input + "\n\n\n" )

    x = f.read()
    print(x)
```

[my codes and text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shewv.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `a+`  Open for reading and appending (**writing at end of file**). The file
>   is created if it does not exist. The initial file position for reading
>   is at the beginning of the file, but output is always appended to the
>   end of the file.

You should use `f.seek()` to set the file offset to the beginning of the file.

```
with open("tryme.txt","a+") as f:
    f.write(Input + "\n\n\n" )
    f.seek(0)
    x = f.read()
    print(x)
```

Output:

```
TYPE: test2
test1


test2
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

After you write to the file, the current position of your reader is at the end of the file. If you want to read the entire file, you need to return to the beginning.

try

```
Input = input("TYPE: ")

with open("tryme.txt","a+") as f:
    f.write(Input + "\n\n\n" )
    f.seek(0,0)
    x = f.read()
    print(x)
```

Comment: If it is not too much to ask, what is the meaning of `f.seek(0,0)`? What is the purpose of the second zero? Anyway, thanks for the help!

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_seek.htm

the second argument of `seek()` is whence. it specifies whether we are taking the offset based on the current position, based on the beginning of the file, or based on the end of the file. It defaults to 0, so it isn't absolutely necessary to include it if you just want to jump to the beginning

Comment: To add further clarity, `f.seek(0,0)` means in file f, from the beginning, go forward an offset of 0. If you write from this position you are prepending the file, and if you read you can read everything after that position. You could specify anywhere in the file. If you want the end you can do `f.seek(0,2)` or if you want to move n characters after the current position `f.seek(n,1)`

Comment: thanks a lot! so that simply means that i can print the contents of my text file from bottom to top, and how i like it?

Comment: `seek` is essentially equivalent to moving a cursor in a text file. It is mostly for finding the end of a file for writing again or the beginning or some specified line for reading. You can't use seek to print from the bottom to the top. Unless of course, you use it in a loop repeatedly to move one line from the bottom at a time printing whatever you get from `readline()` When you read it will always move down the file. If you want to read something twice you would also use seek, because once you reach the bottom, reading only returns `''`

Comment: that explains a lot. thanks for the clear explanation. kudos to you!